# puxar estrutura do site através do banco de dados

Tags: php, html

Tenho uma dúvida eu tenho um site relativamente grande onde uma seção do site se repete muitas vezes a onde a estrutura e igual em todas as páginas o que muda é o o conteúdo que é puxado pelo banco de dados mais queria saber se posso por a estrutura  hmlt php dentro do banco de dados pois caso eu queira por exemplo por uma dív ou qual quer outro elemento eu vo te que editar página por página então seria melhor criar a página e puxar sua estrutura HTML pelo banco de dados aí assim todas as outras mudariam também

Comment: Eu recomendaria usar um framework tipo vuejs, laravel...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em particular prefiro criar uma pagina mestre com a estrutura html e dar um include nas outras paginas.

---

```
<--Estrutura da pagina mestre-->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- Imprime o titulo da pagina filho -->
    <title>Página Mestre | <?php echo $titulo; ?></title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Menu -->
    <nav></nav>

    <!-- Conteudo da pgina filho -->
    <?php echo $conteudo; ?>

    <!-- Roda Pé -->
    <footer></footer>
</body>
```

---

```
<-- Página filho -->

<?php ob_start(); ?>

<!-- Conteudo da pagina filho vai aqui -->

<?php
$conteudo = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
// Titulo da pagina filho
$titulo = 'Home';
// Include da página mestre
include_once 'pagina_mestre.phtml';
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda não tinha pensado em fazer desse jeito muito bom

Comment: voce poderia me ajudar pois o conteudo nao aparece

Comment: Acredito que você tenha que executar a página filho ao invés da página mestre nesse caso, pois a página filho está incluindo a página mestre(include_once 'pagina_mestre.phtml';).

Comment: Sim você deve chamar a página filho e não a página mestre. E detalhe você pode ter mais de uma página filho por exemplo Home, Serviços,  Projetos, Contato  e etc incluindo a página mestre.

Answer (score 1):

Não é necessário utilizar banco de dados, basta você utilizar [include](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.include.php)
ou include_once, que tem como objetivo no php é "trazer o texto de outro arquivo" para a página onde o include foi utilizado. Então você poderá pegar esses arquivos que se repetem e incluí-los nas outras páginas, e quando quiser editar basta editar esse arquivo separado.

Comment: Sim obrigado pela ajuda